# Visual Studio 2019 C# Hotkey for seeing application of function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hotkeys

I am new to coding C# in Visual Studio. In particular, the latest 2019 version.

I know that pressing `ctrl + F12` on a function will see its implementation.

However, which hotkey should I press on a function to see its application, i.e., where is it called.

Does it even exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Find All References" - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The Find All References command is available on the context (`right-click`) menu of the element you want to `find references` to. Or, if you are a keyboard user, press `Shift + F12`.

[more details about references...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-references?view=vs-2019)

[image]